# How can I make a long strand of bones without having to extrude each one?

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

How can I make a long strand of bones without having to extrude each one? Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Subdivide One Large Bone

Thankfully there is a very easy way to do this: simply create one large bone the length you want your final strand of bones to be, then Subdivide that bone repeatedly:

Select bone -> <kbd>TAB</kbd> -> <kbd>W</kbd> -> Subdivide

[image]

Comment: After selecting subdivide you can also press F6 (or use the panel at the bottom of the tools sidebar) and change the number of cuts.